# In the view at the end of The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring, where is Mordor?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, movie

This is a screenshot near the end of the movie Fellowship of the Ring:

[image: Screenshot from the end of the Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring, with the Emyn Muil in front, the Dead Marshes after them and Mordor in the distance. In the front, Sam and Frodo are viewed from behind, looking at this all.]

Frodo said: "Mordor...". I think he was talking about the area in front of him. Was the mountains area in front Mordor? Was Mordor at the back of the screenshot, separated by a sea?

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious he was talking about the evil glow in the distance. I don't see Sauron's tower anywhere in that mountain range in front of them.

Comment: That's not a sea, it's a bog where the last alliance initially defeated Sauron in the last age.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Check out this map:

[image]

At the moment of the screenshot you posted, Frodo and Sam are near the top-left corner of that map, looking roughly south-east (down and to the right on the map).  The Falls of Rauros, noted at the top-left of the map, was where Boromir's body tumbled over the waterfall, very near to where Frodo and Sam are standing in that screenshot.

The rocky area immediately in front of them is Emyn Muil (the top-left mountains on the map).  Beyond that is the Dead Marshes (the flat plain in the screenshot, reflecting light because of its watery surface).  The black mountain range in the distance is the border of Mordor.

Mordor itself stands behind those distant mountains, where we can see the faint red glow in the clouds.

Comment: you think the area which looked like sea was Dead Marshes?

Comment: @Iamwaiman1988 - We saw Frodo, Sam and Gollum cross the Dead Marshes in *The Two Towers*--that was the place in the film where they saw the dead bodies under the water, and one of the bodies reached out to grab Frodo before Gollum saved him (see the clip [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6YKD5hCShI) starting around 2:10, and 2:48 where Gollum says "The Dead Marshes--yes, yes, that is their name")--so the screenshot in your question from the end of *Fellowship* must have been before they reached the Dead Marshes.

Comment: (cont) As for the body of water seen in your screenshot, that didn't look like the marshes which were a mix of land and water, so I'd guess that in that screenshot they had yet to cross the river [Anduin](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Anduin) (the main river on the left side of the map) and that's what they were seeing in the near distance.

Comment: @Hypnosifl It's definitely the marshes.  They crossed the river before that shot was taken, when Sam chased Frodo into the water and almost drowned.  Compare it to other [Dead Marshes pics](http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20070614162009/lotr/images/2/29/Dead-marshes.jpg), and it's clear that much of the surface is water.  We can also see the surface broken up by land in OP's screenshot, as it is in the Dead Marshes scenes.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I had forgotten about the scene of them crossing the river earlier, and looking at that shot in hi def on the blu ray, what I had taken to be glints of light on a smooth body of water in the screenshot were actually patches of water in between darker regions of land.

Answer (score 50):

This scene takes place shortly after Frodo and Samwise depart from the fellowship. That occurred near the [Falls of Rauros](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Falls_of_Rauros).

> At the breaking of the Fellowship of the Ring, Frodo and Sam paddled a boat from the west bank of the river to the east just above the falls and had to use all their strength to avoid being swept over the falls by the current.

East of the falls, where they're standing in the screenshot, is [Emyn Muil](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Emyn_Muil) (if you Google images for that, several copies of the screenshot you posted show up).

Given that information, it's clear in the image that the foreground rocks are those of Emyn Muil, the flat area further out is the Dead Marshes, and the mountains in the distance are those that border Mordor.

They are approximately standing the circle drawn on this map, with the field of view indicated toward Mordor.

[image]
(I got the map from [here](http://blog.lefigaro.fr/hightech/middle-earth-map.jpg))

Comment: @JasonBaker It was done in MS Paint though...

Comment: No excuses! ([Should I point out that I'm joking? I'm joking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/276025))

Comment: @JasonBaker No, you shouldn't have pointed that out. And yet, here we are.

Comment: Easy solution (and **more** accurate:) - You could make your circle into a point located just to the left of top of the "f" in "of" in "Falls of Rauros" and have your lines radiate out from there about like you have them drawn now.

Comment: @user23715 That actually may be less accurate and only slightly more precise.

Comment: Best answer because the map actually has pointers on it.

Comment: Why is Sputnik shown on the map?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Ah, that's just an optical illusion. It's actually high *above* the map, in orbit.

Answer (score 23):

Using your own screenshot, I've highlighted where [Mordor](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Mordor) is - the mountain range in the far distance. The orange glow in the clouds near the top center of the image is their destination, [Mount Doom](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Mount_Doom) (the volcano where the One Ring was forged), and that mountain range represents the outer rim of the Black Land.

The flat, watery area in the middle is [The Dead Marshes](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Dead_Marshes), which Frodo & Sam can be seen walking across later in [The Two Towers](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/The_Two_Towers_(film)) (along with Gollum). I've highlighted that area as well. Below your screenshot is a more recognizable view of the marshes. In that view, you can see the mountainous edge of Mordor in the distance as Frodo & party make their way through the marshes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know, I know... I used lazy, souless circles. But I was in a hurry.

Comment: You will return to correct this faux pas when you do have time, yes?

Comment: +1 for your annotation of their images.  But where in New Zealand was this?